# INSERT INTO not inserting for me

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I can't see anything wrong with this, but it just wont work.

Quick rundown: Form filled in on previous page, $_POST['']'s added to $_SESSION['']'s, $vars set from the $_SESSION['']'s, $vars used to mysqli_query.

Im sure the problem is staring me in the face, but I just cant see it.

Heres the code: (UPDATED)

```
if(isset($_POST['list_make']) && $_POST['list_make'] != '') { $list_make  = $_POST['list_make']; $_SESSION['list_make'] = $list_make; }
if(isset($_SESSION['list_make']) && $_SESSION['list_make'] != '') { $list_make = $_SESSION['list_make']; } else { $list_make = ''; }

$add_car_query = "INSERT INTO car_details 
    (car_user_id, car_user_number, car_date_added, car_make, car_model, car_date_registered, car_odometer, 
        car_engine_size, car_color, car_body_type, car_owners, car_nct_date, car_rax_date) 
    VALUES 
    ('$user_id_new', '$new_user_number', '$today', '$list_make', '$list_model', '$list_year', '$list_kilometers', 
        '$list_engine_size', '$list_color', '$list_body_type', '$list_previous_owners', '$list_nct', '$list_tax')
    ";
if(mysqli_query($con, $add_car_query)) { $added = 'added'; } else { $added = 'Not happening'; }
```

Comment: "Won't work" can often be better qualified by `mysqli_error()`. It's easy to surmise lack of database escaping here though.

Comment: You should use prepared statements. Now your code is very insecure!

Comment: As mario says, include a call to `mysqli_error()` in your else part.  Then update your question with the error message.  Marcin Nabiałek is right about prepared statements.

Comment: Did you notice that you didn't even care explaining what branch of the if/else executes?

Comment: No error is being returned, if it was, I would know where the issue is :p

Comment: I have no idea what you mean Álvaro, I thought it was obvious that it executes the the query added to the $add_car_query variable.

Comment: maybe you have error reporting off try `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Hey Andrew, yep, have error reporting on, still not showing anything. I would have expected at least an error saying 0 parameters given if something wasnt getting passed in the variables, but not even getting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking if there is a MySQLi error in the `else` (which will be triggered if the query fails):

```
$add_car_query = "INSERT INTO car_details 
    (car_user_id, car_user_number, car_date_added, car_make, car_model, car_date_registered, car_odometer, 
        car_engine_size, car_color, car_body_type, car_owners, car_nct_date, car_rax_date) 
    VALUES 
    ('$user_id_new', '$new_user_number', '$today', '$list_make', '$list_model', '$list_year', '$list_kilometers', 
        '$list_engine_size', '$list_color', '$list_body_type', '$list_previous_owners', '$list_nct', '$list_tax')
    ";
if(mysqli_query($con, $add_car_query)) { 
  $added = 'added'; 
} 
else { 

  // check for the error here
  if(mysqli_error()) {
    echo mysqli_error();
  }

  $added = 'Not happening'; 
}
```

---

**Prepared Statements**

As someone in the comments said, you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for better security. This way you don't have to worry about escaping input (it looks like you aren't escaping the values right now which is [very dangerous](http://bobby-tables.com/)).

It can get a bit confusing with the question mark placeholders though (MySQLi doesn't support named parameters unfortunately). Prepared statements are nicer with OOP MySQLi, but you're using procedural so here's how you do a prepared statement for the query in your question:

```
$add_car_query = "INSERT INTO car_details 
    (car_user_id, 
     car_user_number, 
     car_date_added, 
     car_make, 
     car_model, 
     car_date_registered, 
     car_odometer, 
     car_engine_size, 
     car_color, 
     car_body_type, 
     car_owners, 
     car_nct_date, 
     car_rax_date) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($con, $add_car_query);

// if any of the values are an int, change the 
// corresponding 's' (which means string) to 'i' (integer).
// more info: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssss', 
                       $user_id_new, 
                       $new_user_number, 
                       $today, 
                       $list_make, 
                       $list_model, 
                       $list_year, 
                       $list_kilometers, 
                       $list_engine_size, 
                       $list_color, 
                       $list_body_type, 
                       $list_previous_owners, 
                       $list_nct, 
                       $list_tax);
$stmt_exe = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if($stmt_exe) { 
   $added = 'added'; 
} 
else { 
   if(mysqli_error()) {
     echo mysqli_error();
   }
   $added = 'Not happening'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I learn something new every day! :) The actual issue, I discovered was indeed staring me in the face... all I was really looking for was a second set of eyes (instead I got people downing the little reputation I have here) to see if anything in the code was out of place.. which it was, a typo in 'car_tax_date;, I had 'car_rax_date'..   Thanks again for taking the time to post this code tho, will be helpful to me indeed :) I cant vote up because I dont have 15 rep yet, but as soon as I do, i will be back!

Comment: @EoinH No problem, I'm glad you found the issue! I'm surprised I didn't see the typo. I guess I wasn't really paying attention to the variable and column names. Also even though you can't upvote yet you could still accept my answer if the first part of it helped with finding the error :)